# What does the "REGENERATE" button do?

Tags: titanfall-2

At some level (possibly 50?), a button shows in your multiplayer menus below "SETTINGS" called "REGENERATE".

What are the consequences of clicking this button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally caved.

Clicking the "REGENERATE" button will take you to a black screen that has text which scrolls in. Upon all the text loading, there is a singular option to click which is highlighted (as well as B for cancel on xb1). It reads:

> Upgrade Pilot to G2.00

To note, if you have done this before it should be your G number, although if you have done this before you already know this process anyway.

The text which scrolls in reads:

> Years of battle have taken their toll. We can regenerate you...at a cost.
>   Your body can be restored. But much of your memory and experience will be lost.
>   These you will have to earn all over again in battle.
>   When you awaken, you will respawn as a next generation pilot.
>
> Would you like to go to the next gen?
>
> **-** An advocate

After which a block of text beneath the slow loading text appears at once,

> Warning: Regeneration gives access to new cosmetic unlocks, but there is a cost. Your pilot's unlock progression is reset as though you were level 1, meaning you'll have to unlock weapons, boosts, titans, and factions again (unless purchased with credits).
>   Credits and callsigns are unaffected.
>
> Your weapon, titan, and faction progress is frozen until you unlock them again.

Selecting "Upgrade to pilot G2.00" brings you to another screen asking "are you sure?", and then "are you really sure?", and then gives you one final "last chance to back out!"

Continuing loads a video and then you return to the same options screen as prior. **There are the same availability of unlocks as level 1, and all of the pilot loadouts are set to default** ( <strike>including their names</strike> this was patched in January '17, names are now retained).

In addition to the default set of unlocks available at level 1, any unlocks that were paid for will also be available (for example other factions or one of my favorites the satchel). Any weapon accessories will be available, as well as titan accessories - however you will still need to unlock the titan or weapon itself in order to use it again if it is not available at level 1 or has not been purchased.

Regneration complete.

Answer (score 4):

[Regeneration in Titanfall](http://twinfinite.net/2016/10/titanfall-2-regeneration-how-to/) 2 is akin to Prestiging in Call of Duty:

> Just like its predecessor, Titanfall 2 has a regeneration system which
>   sees you essentially Prestiging your character. While in the original
>   game the only thing that could regenerate was your character,
>   Titanfall 2 brings the feature to a number of different elements.
>
> First thing’s first, let’s explain what regeneration is. As we just
>   mentioned, it’s very much like Prestiging in Call of Duty. Each time
>   you hit the maximum rank, you can reset all of your unlocks and
>   customization options to hit the next generation. Doing so will grant
>   you the ability to unlock some of the rarest skins and items in the
>   game, so it’s definitely worth doing if you get the option.
>
> What’s different in Titanfall 2, however, is the number of different
>   things that have the regeneration feature. Not only can you regenerate
>   your character, but your Titans and weapons too. Once a specific Titan
>   or weapon hits its maximum level, you’ll be given the option to
>   regenerate. Doing so will then allow you to unlock skins exclusive to
>   that weapon and that generation. Continue to regenerate weapons,
>   Titans, and your character to eventually unlock everything.
>
> It’s also important to note that regenerations no longer require you
>   to complete a set list of challenges either. Now, it’s purely a case
>   of getting your equipment or character to the maximum level.
>
> To regenerate, all you have to do is select the option on the weapon,
>   Titan, or character that is eligible. It’ll be a big option that’s in
>   your face so you can’t miss it either. Confirm the option and bingo,
>   you’ve successfully regenerated.

Comment: This information is incorrect. There is no option to regenerate weapons or titans (it is automatic), also all of the unlocks are not reset (paid unlocks will remain).